# SharePoint List Validation Settings gives me Syntax error

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column-formula, list-validation

```
=IF([Urgency Level] = "XL", IF(ISBLANK([Date and Time of Production Stop just in case of XL]),false,true),true)
```

I get a syntax error message with this formula.

It tells me either the formula doesn't exist anymore or I got a syntax error inside the formula.

Do you guys see what I am doing wrong? This would help me a lot.

Comment: Where are you adding this formula? Display name of date column is correct?

Comment: Yes, the display name is correct. I go to list settings -> validation settings. Thats where i put this formula. But i feel like i get this error message for everything i put in there.

Comment: i want "Date and Time of Production Stop just in case of XL" to be a required field, if Urgency Level is set on "XL".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this formula:

```
=IF([Urgency Level]="XL",IF(ISBLANK([Date and Time of Production Stop just in case of XL]),FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)
```

OR

```
=IF([Urgency Level]="XL",NOT(ISBLANK([Date and Time of Production Stop just in case of XL])),TRUE)
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Make sure you are using correct display names of your columns (case-sensitivity, etc).

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [Examples of common formulas in lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3).

Comment: These don't work either. The sharepoint language is german. Does that mean i have to type the german function names instead maybe? Because if i click on the help me link on ther validation setting site, i get all the function names in german. For example "WENN" instead of "IF". I tried it in german aswell but didn't manage to solve this. Could it maybe be the case that i don't have enough permissions to change the list validation settings?

Comment: Do i need the display names of the columns here or the internal names? These above are the display names

Comment: You should have at least "Edit" or higher (Design/Full Control) permissions on list. Did you try using semicolon in formula like: `=IF([Urgency Level]="XL";NOT(ISBLANK([Date and Time of Production Stop just in case of XL]));TRUE)`.

Comment: In formula, you have to use the display name of the columns.

Comment: This actually worked. Thank you a lot! I guess  have to use semicolon all the time.